# rails path to new returns no route matches when parent is not passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a page in which I create a new account (**views/accounts/new.html.erb**) but when I link to this page I get an error that the parent object (of type kid) id is missing.

```
 <%= link_to (t 'add_account'), new_kid_account_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Error message:

> No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts"} missing required keys: [:kid_id]

In my active record - account belongs to kid and kid has many accounts.

I do not want to pass the kid id, but instead I want the user to choose the kid id or create a new kid in the new account page.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `new_kid_account_path` needs to look something like this:

```
new_kid_account_path(:kid_id => @kid.id)
```

You say you don't want to pass the id, but I'm afraid that's impossible.  What you could do is have the user choose the `kid_id` on the page just before account creation - "Please choose which kid you are opening this account for" - and then pass the chosen `kid_id` to the `link_to` helper

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach you could take. In kids_controller.rb do:

```
before_filter :get_kid

private
def get_kid
  @kid = params[:id].blank? ? Kid.new : Kid.find(params[:id])
end
```

This way a new kid will be instantiated unless you pass id params.

Then your route could be:

```
post 'new_kid', to: 'kids#new', as: new_kid_account
```

Or whatever. The point is to remove :kid_id from the routes file on the new action.